# Application got slower after adding signalr withAutomaticReconnect and set KeepAliveInterval time in rest service

Tags: signalr

Tech stack
Angular 6
signalr Client for Angular 3.0
Asp.Net core 2.0

client application connect with four rest api's. So therefore, there are four hubconnection in client side

```
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(this.signalRurl, {       
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()      
  .build();


   this.bookingConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(this.bookOpsUrl, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
              transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
   .build();




  this.paymentConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(this.payOpsUrl, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
     transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
   })
   .withAutomaticReconnect()
   .build(); 

 this.roomsConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .withUrl(this.roomOpsUrl, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
     transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
   })
   .withAutomaticReconnect()
   .build();
```

I added KeepAliveInterval time for 240 minite in Asp.net core web api

```
services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
                {                   
                    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(240);
                });
```

Now, When I deploy application to the server , I show slowness came from Client application than previous version
So Could you please help me over come this issue

Comment: What exactly has gotten slower? Is it slower for the clients to connect to the hubs? Please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be seeing constant reconnect attempts from the clients because you changed KeepAliveTimeout on the server without updating the ServerTimeout on the clients.
https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options